# What object has a String representation of `{name=value}` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nashorn

I receive a complex `value` in JavaScript (inside the JDK Nashorn engine), that I have to interact with. That value prints to the console as `{shown=true}`. When I say `typeof value` I receive `object` as an answer. When I say `Object.keys(value);` I receive a `TypeError: {shown=true} is not an Object in ...`. Whey I say `value.shown` or `value["shown"]` I always receive a `null`.

What is type is this mysterious object, and how do I access the value of the "shown" property correctly?

Unfortunately, it is not easy to create a simple example and I cannot debug interactively... Any help is highly appreciated!

Edit:
JDK is JavaSE-1.8.

Calling `JSON.parse(value);` results in

```
javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: Invalid JSON: <json>:1:1 Expected , or } but found s
{shown=true}
 ^
```

Comment: which jdk version do you use?

Comment: Have you tried parsing it with `JSON.parse(value)`?

Comment: I have no experience with nashorn, but for JS, `Object.keys()` should work with every value except `null` and `undefined`. Everythnig else can be converted into an Object. You know, the infamous implicit type casting/ambiguity of types in JS. Plus `{ key = value }` is not valid in JS, JS uses `:`. So whatever is wrong with your code/object, it's the Environment, not the language.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you got is a Java object, you should be able to call `value.getClass()` to get its Java class.

From its string representation, it might be an instance of [java.util.HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) or similar. If so, you should be able to access the value of the "shown" property via `value.get("shown")`.